# Project.UnitTests.dll not found when trying to run unit tests in Azure Devops

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-build-task

The error I am getting :

```
The test source file "D:\a\_work\3\s\MyProject.UnitTests\bin\Release\net6.0\MyProject.UnitTests.dll" provided was not found.
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[warning]No test result files were found.
##[warning].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build
```

Related yml script:

```
steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "Run unit tests"
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: "**/*MyProject.UnitTests/*.csproj"
      arguments: --configuration $(projectBuildConfiguration) --no-build --no-restore 
      feedsToUse: 'config'
      nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
```

The tests are running all fine in my local machine.
Project build configuration is release

Comment: Do you have a buid step before the test step?

Comment: @tymtam  Nope, is that causing the issue?

Comment: Remove the no-build flag :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have a separate build step you should **not** be passing the `--no-build --no-restore` flags.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Turned out my "Release" build configuration on my solution was building my Unit Test project using the "Debug" configuration and then my tests.dll was not available under "bin\Release", but under "bin\Debug".
You can change this under the Configuration Manager which updates your solution file. It is stupid and it took me a while to figure out...